# How to force process identical elements individually in a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, iteration, conditional-statements

I am writing a program that tags parts of speech, producing a list of lists. Here is an example function from the program:

```
phrase = [['he',''],['is', ''],['believed', ''],['to',''],['have',''],['believed','']]

def parts_tagger(input_list):
    parts = []
    for [x,y] in input_list:
        prior_word = input_list[input_list.index([x,y]) - 1][0]
        if x.startswith('be') and y == '' and prior_word == 'is':
            parts.append([x,'passive'])
        else:
             parts.append([x,y])
    return parts
print (parts_tagger(phrase))
```

When you run this piece of code, Python finds the first word to which the condition applies (the first "believed") and tags it correctly:

```
[['he', ''], ['is', ''], ['believed', 'passive'], ['to', ''], ['have', ''], ['believed', 'passive']]
```

But then it somehow applies the same tag to other identical words (the second "believed") in the list to which the condition does not apply. What am I doing wrong? How can fix this and force Python to treat each item in the list indivdually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with this line

```
prior_word = input_list[input_list.index([x,y]) - 1][0]
```

[`list.index`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) returns the index of the first match.

> Return the index in the list of ***the first item*** whose value is x. It is an error if there is no such item.

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to solve your problem. Change your loop and the next line to these.

```
for ind,[x,y] in enumerate(input_list): 
    prior_word = input_list[ind - 1][0]
```

The output will be as expected

```
[['he', ''], ['is', ''], ['believed', 'passive'], ['to', ''], ['have', ''], ['believed', '']]
```

---

As [Shawn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5113071/shawn-mehan) pointed out [below (in a now deleted comment)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32416294/how-to-force-process-identical-elements-individually-in-a-list-of-lists/32416321?noredirect=1#comment52699223_32416321), I think that you would need to start with the second index with yourself manually filling the value for the first element. This is because for the first element, you will not have any previous value. There are two work-around(s) for this

1. Start with the second element

   ```
   for ind,[x,y] in enumerate(input_list[1:],start=1):
   ```
2. Add an condition in your body.

   ```
   for ind,[x,y] in enumerate(input_list): 
        prior_index = ind - 1
        if prior_index<0:
             # Do something
             break
        prior_word = input_list[ind - 1][0]
   ```

Comment: Thank you Bhargav. This is perfect. Many thanks also for the tip on how to deal with the first elements. I will go with option (2) because I am working with large lists with numorous conditions. So it would be laborious to manually find where the first occurance is. All Very helpful. Many thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear that you found it useful. All the best.